# logrotate wont compress and delete syslog templated files

Tags: rsyslog, logrotate

I am facing a very weird issue with logrotate and syslog files on my central syslog server. What is happening is that files generated by syslog templates are not compressed nor deleted when logrotate is executed. Other files are compressed and rotated as expected.

**syslog template sample:**

```
    template(name="apache_log" type="string"
     string="/data/logs/apache.log")

    if $syslogtag startswith '(httpd' then {
      action(type="omfile" DynaFile="apache_log" Template="RSYSLOG_SyslogProtocol23Format"
        DirCreateMode="0750" dirOwner="root" dirGroup="logs"
        FileCreateMode="0640" fileOwner="root" fileGroup="logs")
    stop
} 

local2.*  action(name="local2_messageslog" type="omfile"  File="/data/logs/messages")
```

**logrotate sample:**

```
$cat /etc/logrotate.d/syslog

/data/logs/messages
/data/logs/apache.log
{
    sharedscripts
    missingok
    daily
    rotate 4
    postrotate
        /bin/kill -HUP `cat /var/run/syslogd.pid 2> /dev/null` 2> /dev/null || true
    endscript
}
```

**issue:**

```
-rw-r----- 1 root logs  2910357960 Nov  9 03:53 messages
-rw-r----- 1 root logs  1725989639 Nov  6 00:01 messages-20231106.gz
-rw-r----- 1 root logs  1852598019 Nov  7 00:01 messages-20231107.gz
-rw-r----- 1 root logs  2209372695 Nov  8 00:01 messages-20231108.gz
-rw-r----- 1 root logs  2036382265 Nov  9 00:01 messages-20231109.gz

-rw-r----- 1 root logs    82458243 Nov  9 03:53 apache.log
-rw-r----- 1 root logs   501509524 Nov  1 00:01 apache.log-20231101
-rw-r----- 1 root logs   596170609 Nov  2 00:00 apache.log-20231102
-rw-r----- 1 root logs   528313043 Nov  3 00:00 apache.log-20231103
-rw-r----- 1 root logs   475893564 Nov  4 00:00 apache.log-20231104
-rw-r----- 1 root logs    26731791 Nov  5 00:00 apache.log-20231105.gz
-rw-r----- 1 root logs    26634166 Nov  6 00:01 apache.log-20231106.gz
-rw-r----- 1 root logs   518016884 Nov  7 00:01 apache.log-20231107
-rw-r----- 1 root logs   507646042 Nov  8 00:01 apache.log-20231108
-rw-r----- 1 root logs   501009363 Nov  9 00:00 apache.log-20231109
```

The "messages" log file is rotated and compressed as expected. Only 4 rotated files are present. However, for apache log (the syslog templated one), some files are compressed and some others are not. Also, there are log files which are like 8 days old. Logrotate is configured to keep only 4 days. Any ideas may cause this behavior?

The Apache logs are incoming from another system. There is no Apache process running locally.

ps. compress directive is set on logrotate default file

Comment: logrotate will ignore it because apache.log and not apache*. log is being processed imho

Answer (score 0):

You are sending the HUP signal to the syslogd process in the posprocessing phase to indicate that the daemon should recharge the configuration and begin writing in the new messages file, but you are not doing the same thing with apache. If you are using systemd (if not, you should use /etc/init.d/apache2 reload), you should use a postrotate section similar to

```
postrotate
   systemctl reload apache2
```

In some systems the apache service is not apache2 but httpd

Comment: Thanks for the reply, J.M . The Apache logs are incoming logs via TCP from another system. There is no local Apache process running on the node. I will update the post.

Comment: You probably should, then, restart the process that write the remote logs in local files

Comment: Yes this process that writes the remote logs to local file is rsyslog.